# How to create a custom preference with a neutral button?

Tags: android, preferences

I use the code below to create a custom preference.  The xml layout file has a `Button`, `EditText` and `TextView`. This custom layout appears inside an `Alert` with "OK" and "Cancel" buttons.  This all works well.

I would like to add a third button (a neutral button) beside the "OK and "Cancel" buttons.  I've experimented with the `AlertBuilder` class but can't figure out how to incorporate both my custom xml layout and a neutral button.

How can this be done?

Currently have...

```
public class MelsMessage extends DialogPreference {

    Button bMessage;
    EditText eMessage;
    TextView tMessage;

    public MelsMessage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }



    protected View onCreateDialogView() {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_pref_mess, null);

        //UI elements

        bMessage = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonMessage);
        eMessage = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edittextMessage);
        tMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textviewMessage);


        return view;        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

I see your question is a bit old and maybe you already have the answer to your question but here is a solution for your class that extends DialogPreference.

First you have to *Override* the `onPrepareDialogBuilder` method in your **MelsMessage** class:

```
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(AlertDialog.Builder builder)
{
    super.onPrepareDialogBuilder(builder);
    builder.setNeutralButton("hello", this);
}
```

`this` in the `setNeutralButton` method is `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` interface that the **DialogPreference** class implement.

The last thing you have to do is to *Override* the `onClick` method in your **MelsMessage** class:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
{
    super.onClick(dialog, which);

    switch (which)
    {
        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
            // do things for the right button
            break;

        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
            // do things for the left button
            break;

        default:
            // do things for the center button
            break;
    }
}
```

If you want to handle the click in another class all you have to do is to implement `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` in this class.

Hope this will help you. Cheers.

Comment: I used this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20565983/1898523 to include the custom class in XML

Answer (score 0):

When you are overriding `onCreateDialogView` and you don't set the `setPositiveButton` and `setNegativeButton` the ok and cancel button should disappear, don't they? Because in that method you are overriding the default layout and setting a custom one.

If that is the case then you should create you own custom bottom layout with 3 buttons and add it in the inflated one. Try searching and implementing the "bottom ButtonBar" which has all the necessary implementation, because I don't see in the docs any method or a way to implement the neutral button like on a regular Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

you can create custom Dialog with 3 buttons or write code like

```
Dialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {



    } }); 

 Dialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancle", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {



    }}); 

 Dialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Do Nothing" new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


    }});
```