# How to setOnClickListener() to OK button of an EditTextPreference Dialog?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-preferences

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to call the ok button in the EditTextPreference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527894/how-to-call-the-ok-button-in-the-edittextpreference)

I want to validate the Inputs (enter 6 digits) of an EditTextPreference dialog box.

This is how my (relevant) preferences.xml snippet looks like :

```
            <!--EditTextPreference-->
            <com.app.preferences.UpdatePincodePreference
                android:key="PIN_CODE_PREFERENCE"
                android:title="@string/pincode_preference_title" 
                android:summary="@string/pincode_preference_summary"
                android:dialogTitle="@string/pincode_preference_dialog_title"
                android:dialogMessage="@string/pincode_preference_dialog_message" 
                android:inputType="number"
            />
```

How do I test that the user has not entered less or more than 6 digits in the EditText of the preference dialog?

Basically I need to set an onClickListener() on the OK button, but how to I get a hold of the OK button which I did not define. Its the default view of an EditTextPreference, and so is the Cancel button.

The question is exactly the same as "[how to call the ok button in the EditTextPreference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527894/how-to-call-the-ok-button-in-the-edittextpreference)" but the links provided in the accepted solution are broken now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved using setOnPreferenceChangeListener()

```
public UpdatePasswordPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {


    this.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() 
    {   
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) 
        {
            MobicopLogger.d("Preference input changed");
            try 
            {
                if(newValue.toString().length() != 6)
                    return false;
                else
                    return true;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

    });


}
```

Answer (score 2):

The author of the solution has moved his project from Google Code to GitHub. You can find the new project at https://github.com/Knickedi/android-toolbox and the links to the two files he was referring to validating [`DialogPreference`](https://github.com/Knickedi/android-toolbox/blob/39399c5ebe00ccd123cfd79095309c11c88839a0/android_toolbox/src/de/viktorreiser/toolbox/preference/ValidatedDialogPreference.java) and validating [`EditTextPreference`](https://github.com/Knickedi/android-toolbox/blob/39399c5ebe00ccd123cfd79095309c11c88839a0/android_toolbox/src/de/viktorreiser/toolbox/preference/ValidatedEditTextPreference.java)

Comment: Awesome! Thats what I was looking. Seems to be a pretty elaborate solution. Will dig out whats relevant to me. Thnx!

Comment: Cant understand whats happening in the code :(. Can you explain me just the relevant logic. All I need is to check if 6 digits were entered when the user pressed OK button in the EditTextPreference dialog box? Thnx !!!

Answer (score 0):

create a custom layout and apply it to the preference by the following override method  :

```
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(AlertDialog.Builder builder) {
    super.onPrepareDialogBuilder(builder);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    builder.setView(LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.custome_preference_layout,null));
}
```